# What does SysRandom mean in C

Tags: c, random, numbers

I have some source code for the old game DopeWars, and I am trying to convert it to OO Python for some fun practice.

I am trying to figure out the algorithm they use to generate semi-random prices for the different drugs.

This is a copy of the pertinent code.

```
static void makeDrugPrices (int leaveout)
{

    int i, j;

    drugPrices [0] = 1000 + SysRandom (0) % 3500;
    drugPrices [1] = 15000 + SysRandom (0) % 15000;
    drugPrices [2] = 10 + SysRandom (0) % 50;
    drugPrices [3] = 1000 + SysRandom (0) % 2500;
    drugPrices [4] = 5000 + SysRandom (0) % 9000;
    drugPrices [5] = 300 + SysRandom (0) % 600;
    drugPrices [6] = 600 + SysRandom (0) % 750;
    drugPrices [7] = 70 + SysRandom (0) % 180;

    for (i = 0; i < leaveout; i++)
    {
        j = SysRandom (0) % 8;
        drugPrices [j] = 0;
    }
}
```

The only issue is I cannot find any documentation for SysRandom anywhere online. The only other places it is used in the code is in the exact way it is used here. There doesn't seem to be any instantiation or reference to any outside code involving SysRandom.

I am not very familiar with C, so it's possible I am missing something. If you would like the whole source code, I can provide it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe all SysRandom() does is return a random number with 0 as its seed?

Comment: My guess is it calls rand(), where the parameter is the max range, unless the param is 0 then use default.

Comment: It looks like it returns a 32 bit random number. The operation `SysRandom(0) % 3500` results in a random number between 0 and 3500. In the olden days the C function `rand()` only generated a 16 bit random number on Windows, so it was useless for most applications.

Comment: thanks guys, I played with Python a bit after posting this question and I started getting expected values upon generating a random number between 1 and 1000. 

This SysRandom() function/method probably does return a 32 bit random number, and in this implementation it doesn't appear to make a huge difference after a certain order of magnitude (i.e. after 1,000 or 10,000). So 32 bits is probably overkill, but it works anyway.

Anyway, this helped and I'm back on track. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no function `SysRandom` in any C standard library, so it is clearly coming from your project itself or one of its dependencies. You'd have to find it in the source code and see how it's defined.